# Can I give an estimate content length header?

Tags: php, http, stream, http-headers

I'm attempting to send a file while it's being created (which takes many seconds) to a user. I can estimate the size it will be to the nearest kilobyte.

If I create the header and add an extra kilobyte to my estimate (to compensate for minor error) the browser thinks the download failed.

I know I can leave the length off completely but don't think the user experience is as nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RFC 7230 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) specifies:

> If the sender closes the connection or the recipient times out before
> the indicated number of octets are received, the recipient MUST
> consider the message to be incomplete and close the connection.

This means that the content-length header cannot be bigger than the actual content.

There's nothing about making the content-length header smaller than the download, but I think we would both agree that that would not be a good idea.

So the content-length header, surprise - surprise, should reflect the real size of the download.

There's almost always a way to get the real size of the download, are you sure that's impossible in your case?

You cannot add padding to the download to make its size exactly the size mentioned in the header?

Since you don't tell us anything about the download itself I cannot really be more helpful.

Comment: Yeah calculating the real size is extremely difficult (probably possible but would lead to many seconds delay that I don't think is worth it). No way to update the content-length header as the download goes on? Or how would the padding work? Just add a bunch of whitespace to the end of the file to make up the missing bytes?

Comment: The padding completely depends on what the content of your file represents. Headers are sent, as the name suggests, ahead of the content, so no, you cannot change it after you started sending the content.

Comment: FYI: If the `Content-Length` is smaller than the actual message, clients *will* stop reading from the socket. If you cannot determine that size beforehand, consult [RFC 7230, sec. 3.3.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3).